# C , Execute multiple commands in one shell-instance

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, terminal

Is there a way to execute shell-commands in the same shell-instance? Since, `system()` leaves the started shell after the command is executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could always contruct your shell command as a single line command using semicolons. Such as:

```
cd /home/user;mkdir tmp;ls
```

Comment: That's not possible in my case

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean execute the command in the same terminal that run your program? You can achieve that with `popen`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *f = popen("ls", "r");
    char line[1024];
    size_t len;
    while (fgets(line, 1024, f) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    pclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure.. I want to make a "web shell". A website which I can use like a remote shell. So the main() function will be executed by a webserver.
So fare I use system() to execute the commands transferred from the client. But eg. `cd` doesnt work in this way

Comment: If you are writing a web server, you might want to consider languages like node.js, python or php. C is not ideal for a website.